# Is neither ... nor used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, inversion, neither-nor

Consider the following sentence:

> Therefore, they neither need someone else to flatter them, nor depend in great part on a government pension.

1. Is it grammatically a correct sentence?
2. Is there any type of inversion that can be used to make this sentence more formal?

Comment: There is a problem with this. With 'neither/nor' we expect some relation between the alternatives, e.g. "They need neither  food nor water" or "They need neither flattery nor criticism."

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=neither+....+nor+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically correct. Just simplify it and you will find the very common use of ***neither*** as a conjunction with ***nor***. Note: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2) shows that:

> We can use ***neither*** as a conjunction with ***nor***. It connects
> ***two or more negative alternatives***. This can sound formal in speaking:
>
> Therefore, they ***neither need*** X, ***nor depend*** on B

So already your initial sentence is formal enough. If you wish to use an inversion, there are two ways you can rephrase it:

> Therefore, ***neither do they need*** someone else to flatter them, ***nor (do they) depend*** in great part on a government pension.

or

> Therefore, ***they do not need*** someone else to flatter them, ***neither do they depend*** in great part on a government pension.